# How to give border radius in Bar chart react native in android

Tags: react-native, bar-chart

I am trying to give space in chart and number and wants to make bar chat curve from top Like there in number coming on top of chart I have to give space on that and make the chart curve from top. Please suggest , Thanks

I have use react-native-svg npm

```
 const chartConfig = {
    barPercentage: 1,
    barRadius: 55,
  };

<BarChart
      style={{ height: 200 }}
      animate={true}
      animationDuration={500}
      yMin={min}
      yMax={max}
      data={croreValuesPositive}
      yAccessor={({ item }) => item?.value}
      svg={{ fill: colors.red['500'] }}
      chartConfig={chartConfig}
      spacingInner={0.7}
      yAxisLabel=""
      curve={shape.curveMonotoneY}
      verticalLabelRotation={0}
      showValuesOnTopOfBars={true}
      withHorizontalLabels={false}
      withInnerLines={false}
      fromZero={true}
      withVerticalLabels={20}
      contentInset={{
        top: 25,
        bottom: 34,
        left: 5,
        right: 5,
      }}>
      {/* <Grid /> */}
      <Labels labelData={croreValues} />
    </BarChart>
```

Comment: Please add which library you have used.

Comment: react-native-svg npm